# How to create an incremental vector which appends row-wise the values of first N columns using vector operation

Tags: r, vector

In the below sample data frame, the output vector should be `[1] 1,2,6,7,8,8,5,4,3,2,1,9,7,1`

```
P   N   N+1 N+2 N+3 N+4
2   1   2   3   4   5
3   6   7   8   9   10
2   8   5   7   6   5
5   4   3   2   1   9
2   7   1   1   1   1
```

Explanation: Values in P dictates how far to the right side should the data frame values be read and appended into the final vector. 2 means, first two values to the right should be read which gives `[1] 1,2`

If possible, please tell how to do it with and without explicit loop operations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows, use the first value as index (`x[1]`), get the `seq`unece of it, subset the elements in rows without the first element and subset based on the position index from `seq`, then `unlist` the `list` to create the `vector`

```
unname(unlist(apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[-1][seq(x[1])])))
#[1] 1 2 6 7 8 8 5 4 3 2 1 9 7 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(P = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L), N = c(1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
7L), `N+1` = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L), `N+2` = c(3L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 
1L), `N+3` = c(4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 1L), `N+4` = c(5L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: What if column P is not part of the dataframe? How to do it in that case?

Comment: @VirajPanara Then, in the same code, without making much changes, you can do  `cbind(P, df1)` i.e. `unname(unlist(apply(cbind(P, df1), 1, function(x) x[-1][seq(x[1])])))`

Comment: Thanks Arun, I had already upvoted it (my reputation is too low to show it). Accepted the answer now.

Comment: One more follow up question: How can I repeat the values in P incrementally as many times as the values in N columns. In the same example, final vector should be

`1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2`

Comment: Should I raise this as a separate question?

Comment: @VirajPanara Is your expected output correct?  How did you get 1 6 times after the 1, 2, 2,

Comment: @VirajPanara can you post as a new question so that it will be more easier to undrestand

Comment: this is because the 2nd value in P is 3. So, each element of seq(3) is repeated with the corresponding value in N columns (1 repeated 6 times, 2 repeated 7 times, 3 repeated 8 times) and so on

Comment: That's ungrateful! Let me ask this separately and post the link here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714135/creating-a-vector-sequential-elements-of-which-are-repeated-that-many-times-as

Answer (score 1):

**With loops**

dummy data:

```
df = numeric()
for(i in 1:5){
  df = cbind(df, sample(1:5,5))}

> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    2    3    5
[2,]    1    4    5    2    1
[3,]    2    5    1    4    2
[4,]    5    1    3    1    4
[5,]    4    2    4    5    3
```

We append `vec` with the i'th row, from the 2'nd column until the "P'th" (given by df[i,1]) column:

```
vec = numeric()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  vec = c(vec, df[i,2:(df[i,1])])}


> vec
 [1] 3 2 4 1 5 1 3 1 4 2 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, even this is the accepted answer as I asked with and without loop, both. :)